# Laravel 5.2 : Do something after user has logged in?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, event-handling, laravel-5

*(I'm a beginner of Laravel)*

I'm using `Laravel 5.2`. I have successfully enabled the Authentication; by doing the `php artisan make:auth` and stuffs.

So my login is working.

Now i need to do something once someone has logged in. For an simple example:

LOGIN:

- Once a user has logged in, write a value into Session.
- For example: `$request->session()->put('UserAgent', $ClientUserAgent);`

LOGOUT:

- Same thing to do, once a user has logged out, delete the custom Session value.
- For example: `$request->session()->forget('UserAgent');`

I'm not sure whether there are (things like) `hooks` or `Event Listeners`, `Event Handlers`, or something like that.

How can i do it please?

Comment: Could add it to the controller of wherever you are getting redirected to after logging in / registering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Alief's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36491235/775856) below works fine as expected. But as i googled through, using the **Event Handlers** is probably the more preferred way. (It works like custom hooks).

So without any less respects to Alief's Answer below, let me choose --> [this Event Handers approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36493760/laravel-5-2-how-to-access-request-session-classes-from-own-event-listener) i just found out.

Thanks all with regards!

Comment: No problem mate, I also learn something new from your question :)

Answer (score 26):

**For newer versions of Laravel**

If you are only doing something very simple then creating an event handler seems overkill to me. Laravel has an empty method included in the `AuthenticatesUsers` class for this purpose.

Just place the following method inside `app\Http\Controllers\LoginController` (overriding it):

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    // stuff to do after user logs in
}
```

Answer (score 19):

For the post login, you can do that by modifying `App/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php`

Add `authenticated()` into that class to override the default one:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

protected function authenticated(Request $request, User $user) {
   // put your thing in here

   return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

For the logout, add this function into the same class:

```
use Auth;

protected function getLogout()
{
    Auth::logout();

    // do something here

    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: Ermm.. Thanks much! But in the function, do i really need to put all these things? Can't i just put my 1 line of session save code only. (I mean, i don't understand what your codes does)

Comment: Thanks again :)) But i got these Errors: `ErrorException in AuthController.php line 98: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController::authenticated() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given, called in /var/www/html/example.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Aut‌​h/AuthenticatesUsers.php on line 115 and defined`

Comment: Yup i tried exactly. But still shows the same Errors. :D

Comment: I think I know what is wrong, add this in the top of your code:    
      use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Comment: Woah! That's ok now!! Thanksss!!! What would be the function name for "logout" also? :D

Comment: This works actually! (But i wonder if this is a proper way to handle such events, by not using the Event Handlers?) I just wonder! Thanks anyway!! :))

Comment: depending on what you want to do. The controller gets only called by the login page, no? I might be wrong

Comment: Hello! This works fine for me, but when I `dd($user)` it doesn't show me the authenticated user.

Answer (score 4):

You could try setting up event listeners for the Auth events that are fired.

You can setup a listener that listens for `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login` to handle what you need post login and `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout` for post logout.

[Laravel Docs - Authentication - Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#events)

Comment: I actually prefer this way most. But whenever i try this, it gives me Errors. After registering the event in EventServiceProvider (like this: `'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => ['App\Listeners\UserLoggedIn'],` , i can not write to Session from my `app\Listeners\UserLoggedIn.php` file. In the function `public function handle(Login $event) {  ... }`. The session can't be initiated from there.

Comment: Perhaps i have created a new Question separately. Could you please help to jump to there please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36493760/laravel-5-2-how-to-access-request-session-classes-from-own-event-listener

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing, with `authenticated(Request $request, User $user)` method **dont use alert inside this method to test**, it will not show any result, so better put some insert query or something like that to test this method.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simple check for

```
if(Auth::check()){
    //your code
}
```

Make sure you include `use Auth;`

Comment: Simply interesting! :D But at where? (in `routes.php`?) But then how to actually handle the `Login`, and also `Logout` events with this, plsss?

Comment: You can use it in your views . Like if you want to show/display a view to loggedin user then bind that view with in if body.

Comment: Awwwn, i got what you mean. But then this can't handle the events, friend. I need to run some particular codes, once the user has logged in.

Comment: that not work for all pages, that need doing on all system

Comment: -1: OP asks how to get the code to execute in response to the fact of someone logging in. Not how to execute code checking whether someone is logged in.