# Set session data after authenticate user using default auth route in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, session, authentication, laravel-5

I am developing a project using laravel 5.2. I use default authentication in this project by running this command.

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Everything is working great. Now I want to put some data in session after authenticate the user. I can not find the place where I put my code to store data in session after authenticate the user. I googled but not found any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got answer from another question. Here i post the solution for who are looking this type of solution

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36491235/2738927

Comment: This is solution for 5.1, you're using 5.2

Comment: Its working for me now. If I face any problem I will try with your solution

Comment: Just curious what exact version do you use? Because in 5.2.45 there is no `authenticated()` method.

Comment: My laravel version is 5.2.41

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the user is logged in or not using the following code.

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    // The user is logged in...
}
```

Then you can use the session helper class to set the required value in session.

```
session()->set('session_key', 'session_value');
```

Additionally, you can remove the session using the *forget* method.

```
session()->forget('session_key');
```

Resources to read.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-session

Answer (score 0):

In 5.2 you need to override `login()` method from `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` trait in `AuthController.php`.

To set data use `session()` helper in `login()` method:

```
session(['key' => 'value']);
```