# Laravel force user to logout if deleted status

Tags: laravel, authentication

I am trying to force a logout during the login process when a user has a `status` flag of value `0`.

Here's my login code:

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    //protected $redirectTo = '/landlords/dashboard';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function redirectTo()
    {
        $user=Auth::user();
        if($user->account_type == 1){
            return '/t/dashboard';
        }elseif($user->account_type==2){
            return '/l/dashboard';
        } else {
            return '/a/dashboard';
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like `Auth::user()` infers that they are already logged in. How do i proceed in logging out the authenticated user and redirecting to `/login` if they have `$user->status == 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply check `$user` in `redirectTo()`:

```
protected function redirectTo(){
  $user = auth()->user();

  if($user->status == 0){
    auth()->logout();
    return '/login';
  }

  if($user->account_type == 1){
    return '/t/dashboard';
  } else if($user->account_type==2){
    return '/l/dashboard';
  } else {
    return '/a/dashboard';
  }
}
```

An argument can be made that you shouldn't let the user login if they have a `status` of `0`, and that would simply be done by overriding the login logic. I don't personally use Laravel's default auth logic, so I can't advise on that approach, but it should be an option.

Comment: Just to complement this answer when it says "you shouldn't let the user login if they have a status of 0", in the documentation there is an example in which you will only have to change `'active' => 1` to  `'status' => 1` [Specifying Additional Conditions](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#authenticating-users)

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ I would actually add that as it's own answer; it seems more logical to block login in that instance instead of going through the trouble of login, check property, force logout. I just don't actually know the approach for default Auth. I use a custom version of Sentinel auth for almost all of my projects.

Comment: imho `authenticated()` method may be used instead of `redirectTo()`. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49097885/6274211)

Answer (score 5):

Just to complement @Tim Lewis answer, you can also avoid the user login if doesn't have a status == 1, adding an extra condition to the authentication query in addition to the user's e-mail and password. [Specifying Additional Conditions](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#authenticating-users)

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'status' => 1])) {
        // all ok, you can redirect the user
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Also you can create a middleware that checks that field in the logged in user, in case the user is already logged in when the status changes:

```
artisan make:middleware CheckStatus
```

then in `\app\http\Kernel.php`, in the `$routeMiddleware` array, add:

```
//you can change checkStatus to canBeLogued, or whatever you want, I'm not good it english at all
'checkStatus' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckStatus::class,
```

then in `\app\http\Middleware\CheckStatus.php`, something like this in the handle method:

```
if(Auth::check() && Auth::User()->status == 0)
     Auth::logout();
     return redirect()->to('/login')->with('warning', 'Your session has expired because your status change.');
}
return $next($request);
```

then, apply that middleware to the routes you want. If it's applicable to all the routes, you could do something like this in web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'checkStatus'], function () {
    //all your protected routes
});
```

Comment: can achieve this by overriding the `credentials` method:  `protected function credentials(Request $request) { return $request->only($this->userName(), 'password') + ['status' => 1]; }`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. By redirecting once logged in is a waste of resources and could involve security issues. The user shouldn't be able to log in if `status` flag is 0.
Otherwise, you are logging in the user, checking the flag and then login out the user. A really bad practice.

Comment: `Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'status' => 1])` might not be able to show the user that he has valid credentials but not active status. Rather it will always say `invalid credentials`. The post login approach would make sense to user.

Comment: @ab.in you are right, it will not be able to show to the user a specific message if what failed was credentials or status, I suppose you can also change the message from 'These credentials do not match our records.' to 'These credentials do not match our records or your status does not allow you to log in' on `resources/lang/en/auth.php`. I think you can add that approach as an answer.

Comment: An approach through authorization policy may also be interesting. It would have to be studied a bit how to implement it for this particular case but I just found it and I share it just FYI https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authorization#policy-responses