# Perform post route controller logic after login only when specific button is clicked without just getting redirected towards original page in Laravel

Tags: laravel, redirect, post, routes

How to perform post route action after successfully authenticating user. Consider i have a post route which adds products to wish-list on clicking the wish-list button. But the controller contains an auth middleware, so when a user is not logged in and clicks on the wish-list button, he/she is redirected towards the login route. Currently after logging in my user is getting redirected towards the product listing page. but i want it to perform the addition of product logic inside my controller after login and then redirect to the necessary page as mentioned in controller. I have provided my code below:

ProductController

```
/**
         * Create a new controller instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct() {
            $this->middleware('auth')->only('addToWishList');
        }

    public function addToWishList($productId) {
            // Checking if product exist in wish list
            if (User::checkUserProductCount(auth()->user()->id, $productId, 1) > 0) return redirect()->route('userWishlist')
                ->with('success', 'Product already present in wish-list');
            
            // adding the product
            User::addProductToUserWishList(User::getUserById(auth()->user()->id), $productId);
            
            return redirect()
                ->route('userWishlist')
                ->with('success', 'Product has been added to wish-list');
        }
```

UserController

```
public static function checkUserProductCount($userId, $productId, $type) {
            return count(self::getUserProduct($userId, $productId, $type));
        }
        
        public static function getUserProduct($userId, $productId, $type) {
            return DB::table('product_user')
                ->where('user_id', $userId)
                ->where('product_id', $productId)
                ->where('type', $type)
                ->get();
        }

    public static function addProductToUserWishList($userCollection, $productId) {
            $userCollection
                ->products()->attach([
                    $productId => [
                        'type' => 1 // 1 is wish list here
                    ]
                ]);
        }

    public static function getUserById($userId) {
            return User::where('id', $userId)
                ->firstOrFail();
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.2 : Do something after user has logged in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491035/laravel-5-2-do-something-after-user-has-logged-in)

Comment: I guess no, because i specifically need to perform the action only when the button is clicked! Is it possible to achieve the same via Event Handler as suggested in the link you provided?